# How do I limit a jquery selector to only children of an element with a particular ID?

Tags: jquery

I have a selector like this, which selects input elements of type text.

```
$('input[type=text]')
```

How do I limit it to only select input elements of type text that are contained in an element with a particular ID? For instance, how do I select input fields of type text that are children of A?

```
<article id="A">
    <p>Concrete</p>
    <div class="form">
        <fieldset>
            <input placeholder="Quantity" type=
            "text"> </input>   <!-- select these -->
</article>
<article id="B">
    <p>Concrete</p>
    <div class="form">
        <fieldset>
            <input placeholder="Quantity" type=
            "text"> </input>  <!-- not these -->
```

Answer (score 1):

To find *all the `input[type="text"]` elements within `#A`:

```
$('#A').find('input[type=text]');
```

Or:

```
$('#A input[type=text]');
```

Or, to find only the direct children of `#A` that are `input[type="text"]`:

```
$('#A').children('input[type=text]');
```

References:

- [`children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).

Answer (score 1):

You can search for another selector inside an element with given ID using this syntax:

```
$('#<id>').find('<your-selector>')
```

So, in your particular case, you can use:

```
$('#A').find('input[type=text]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$('#A input[type=text]')
```

Comment: This works, but it's not recommended to do it this way. It's slower than David's solution because it can't take advantage of the browser's quick ID lookup.

Comment: @Mark - is it really slower to do this instead of `find` or `children`?

Comment: @Mark: that's not necessarily true; while it might not be *as* quick, the jQuery can implement/call upon the browser's native [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll) (if available), which is only *marginally* slower, and *does* prevent the need for a second look-up.

Comment: I dunno. This is what my IDE tells me every time I try to write something like that. Too lazy to jsperf it because it probably doesn't matter in practice.